# We need additional time to evaluate your submission and Apple Developer Program account

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, review

My App update was Rejected and Apple has sent me a message :

```
 Hello,
Thank you for submitting your app for review.
We need additional time to evaluate your submission and Apple Developer Program account. Your submission status will appear as "Rejected" in App Store Connect while we investigate. However, we do not require a revised binary or additional information from you at this time.
While there may be a delay due to high submission volumes, we are working to complete our review as soon as possible. If we notice any issues that require your attention, we will let you know via App Store Connect. If we find no issues with your submission or account, the submission will be approved.
We will notify you as soon as there is new information to share. Other review inquiries may be filed via the Apple Developer Contact Us page.

Best regards,
App Store Review iOS App 1.1.2
 App Version
Rejection Reasons:
Other Reply to App Review
```

Has anyone else had the same experience? How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Any updated?
My account all apps are rejected, and sent me the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have met this message several times. Typically this means your review may be delayed for more days. Last time we waited for 7 days, and on the 8th day, we wrote a mail asking what's the review progress. Then the apple review team replied and continued its review.

So I suggest you wait patiently and reduce the submission frequency. And better not use private APIs next time.

Comment: it's about a month to go

Comment: Consider resubmitting a new build, Abir.

Comment: @kakaiikaka what does private APIs have anything to do with this?

Comment: yeah, several years ago, we used private APIs to get Wi-Fi signal strength(via method swizzling), then suddenly, in one submission, we received one message that contains "we need additional time to evaluate your submission..."